# vector in SVJour3 template

Tags: amsmath

How I can get the vector symbol using SVJour3 template. I already define

```
\usepackage{amsmath}
\let\vec\mathbf
```

but it is not working.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! Not working in what sense? I tried and apart from a warning I get the expected output.

Comment: @egreg, in the sense that when im writing $\vec{x}$ i got x as ouptut while im looking to get x with an arrow above it

Comment: Well, `\let\vec\mathbf` is definitely not helping, then.

Comment: @egreg, so can i  get the desired vector output

Comment: Added an answer. Not very clean code, but I blame `svjour3` for not allowing better strategies.

Comment: @egreg, thank you. your trick solution works for me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Other Springer classes have the `vecarrow` option for that, but `svjour3` doesn't.

You can still reinstate vector with arrows, with a slightly dirty trick.

```
% save the original definition of \vec
\let\latexvec\vec

\documentclass[smallextended]{svjour3}

% restore the original over the svjour3 version
\let\vec\latexvec

\usepackage{amsmath}

\begin{document}

A vector $\vec{v}$.

\end{document}
```

A different trick:

```
\documentclass[smallextended]{svjour3}

% remove the definition of \vec by svjour3
\let\vec\relax
% restore the original definition in fontmath.ltx
\DeclareMathAccent{\vec}{\mathord}{letters}{"7E}

\usepackage{amsmath}

\begin{document}

A vector $\vec{v}$.

\end{document}
```

The two tricks are essentially equivalent; the former has the advantage you needn't look up how `\vec` is originally defined by LaTeX.

It's important to restore the original definition before loading `amsmath`, because this package will redefine it to behave with its constructs (but not changing the final shape).

[image]